# Error while installing node module in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I just cloned a React application from Git that doesn't have `node_modules` on it. I try to install with command `npm install` but unable to do it. Following error occurs when installing the npm.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: fuse-react-app@2.0.0
npm ERR! Found: date-fns@2.0.0-alpha.26
npm ERR! node_modules/date-fns
npm ERR!   date-fns@"2.0.0-alpha.26" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer date-fns@"2.0.0-alpha.21" from @date-io/date-fns@1.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@date-io/date-fns
npm ERR!   @date-io/date-fns@"1.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-24T12_44_19_589Z-debug-0.log
```

I even tried with `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` but doesn't work. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried setting the version of `date-fns` in `package.json` to `2.0.0-alpha.21`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

A possible solution to this problem is setting the version of `date-fns` to `2.0.0-alpha.21`.

---

**Full Answer**

To fix your issue, you can change the version of `date-fns`.

To do this, follow these steps.

1. In `package.json`, edit the version of `date-fns` with the following:

   ```json
   {
     "dependencies": {
       "date-fns": "2.0.0-alpha.21"
     }
   }
   ```
2. Save the `package.json` file, and run the following command in the same directory as `package.json`.

   ```
   $ npm install
   ```
3. Your dependencies should install successfully.

---

**Conclusion**

In conclusion, you need to change the version of `date-fns` to `2.0.0-alpha.21`.